# Django, register user with first name and last name?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django-Registration and the form just has 3 fields (Username, Email, Password, and Re-password), but why I can't add last name and first name??

In the Form all is fine but the User Model just accepts 3 arguments:

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

but why I can't do that:

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password, first_name ,last_name)
```

The Django Documentation doesn't say anything about just 3 arguments; all tutorials on the net just use 3 arguments...

Why?? Or how will I make use of first and last name?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I did it :

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
new_user.is_active = False
new_user.first_name = first_name
new_user.last_name = last_name
new_user.save()
```

Comment: You missed  new_user.save() at the end.

Answer (score 12):

I know you found a way around, but this way below may also interest you.
This is because it requires keywords arguments (which will be passed to the User's `__init__` method).
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#manager-methods

```
User.objects.create_user("user1", "user1@foo.bar", "pwd", first_name="First", last_name="Last")
```