# Adding first name and last name to Django-Registration

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have used the default Django `registration` (version 0.8) in my project where users only input their username, email, and password. However, I want users to also input their first name and last name on the registration page.  How can I do this easily?

Comment: You can see an easy solution in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382205/django-register-user-with-first-name-and-last-name

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is override the default UserRegisterForm and create a new field overriding it .

Create a new file named forms.py or whatever. Import in your views and use this form instead .

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    email  = forms.EmailField(max_length = 100)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput() , max_length = 100)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(),  max_length = 100)
    first = forms.CharField(max_length = 100 )
    last = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)

    class Meta  : 
        fields = "__all__"
        
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        if not username : 
            raise forms.ValidationError("UserName cannot be empty !")

        try : 
            user = User.objects.get(username = username)
        except :
            user = None

        if user : 
            raise forms.ValidationError("User with the username -: {} already exits ".format(username))

        return username    

    def clean_first(self) :
        first = self.cleaned_data.get("first")
        if not first: 
            raise forms.ValidationError("Kindly enter your first name !")
            
    def clean_last(self) :
        last = self.cleaned_data.get("last")
        if not last: 
            raise forms.ValidationError("Kindly enter your last name !")

    # in what ever field you want to apply validations and authentications create a function named "clean_{field_name}" and get the data from the cleaned_data attribute .
```