# How to add first name and last name to Django-registeration-redux registeration form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm using Django-redux but the registeration form only accepts username, email and password. However, I also want to accept **first name** and **last name** and also **fields from other models** like profile pic and city.. I could only find this question: [Adding first name and last name to Django-Registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023493/adding-first-name-and-last-name-to-django-registration) and it's not answered.

This is in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
```

and this is in my template:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

I also want to add this form to the registration form:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = UserProfile
            fields = ('profilepic', 'city')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Add your field in models (models.py)

```
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Step 2. Delete your migration folder and delete tables from database

Step3. use make migration command and then migrate your project.

Hope its solve your problem.

Or you use this..

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
new_user.is_active = False
new_user.first_name = first_name
new_user.last_name = last_name
new_user.save()
```

Comment: Hi Suresh, could you clarify on how to properly implement the first and last name? Do I have to create a new class and add them? I mean, I already have a project where redux is running but now I have decided to add first name and last name to the registration and want to find the best way to add them into the registration form. Would appreciate it!